# What is the common properties between a matrix $A$ and $PAP^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $P$ be a $n \times n$ matrices and $A$ is not a full-rank matrix. ($P$ is invertible). ($P^T$ is a tranpose of a matrix $P$)
I knew that $A$ and $P A P^T$ is not similar, but I guess that there is some common property.... I knew that they have same rank, but I want more properties.

What is that?

Comment: it is called congruence

Comment: oh i didnt know the name! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between $A$ and $PAP^T$ is called [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). If two matrices are congruent then they are matrix representations of the same [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form).

Sylvester's law of inertia states that for a real **symmetric** (thanks, RideTheWavelet) matrix $A$, $A$ and $PAP^T$ have the same number of positive, zero, and negative eigenvalues. (Consequently, rank is preserved.) In particular, if $A$ is positive semi-definite, then $PAP^T$ is as well.

Comment: An important point that you're missing is that $A$ must be symmetric for Sylvester's LoI to hold.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will search and study it :)